# Cloning my SSD into bigger one

Tags: ssd

I have a 128gb SSD running MacOSX, I have another 2TB spinning disk too, I have a bunch of symlinks so that ordinary directories that do not need SSD speed are put on the 2TB disk (Downloads, Desktop, etc, for example).

I have purchased a bigger and faster SSD and I would like to replace my existing SSD with this new one.

I have set it up on an external disk mount that connects via USB, and cloned my main using Carbon Copy Cloner and SuperDupper, with both I could not get it to BOOT after I replaced my main disk with the bigger one inside the casing.

What am I doing wrong?
What I did:
- Partition virgin SSD with 1 full size partition using disk utility with boot GUID Partition Table.
- Use CCC or SupperDupper to clone it.
- Open up machine, replace old SSD with new SSD.
- Turn on computer.

It will always fail to boot. So I just go back to using my original SSD.

Comment: You may try this : Format the new SSD, install Mac OS X on it. Then try to boot on it externally. Then put it inside the Mac and try to boot. If you cannot boot, then the problem comes from using the SSD. If you can boot, then the problem comes from the cloning.

Comment: what kind of fail? I don't think you are wrong, but an important thing, after you changing the SSD, the Mac cann't got he startup disk, you it will take long time to startup

Comment: Didnt work, when installing Macosx it will ask me to restart my computer, and after that it does not continue with the install. Unless there is another way to install without restarting I am stuck again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it.

After countless tries, here is what worked for me :

Format your new disk using macsx extended (journaled) and with GUID boot table.

Clone your disk into the other disk (in my case SSD to SSD) using Carbon Copy Cloner.
Then go on AppleLogo->System Preferences->Startup Disk and select the disk that you cloned INTO (destination).

Press restart, and it will appear in the booting options.

In my case, after it shows in the boot options I can select it and boot from it (even tho it is still external).

Hackintosh only:
In my case this wasnt the final step, since, after removing the original disk and mounting the new disk it still wouldnt boot.

So, I plugged the OLD disk into the USB external case, so the boot options would show, booted from the NEW disk as in previous step (settings->startup), and then Ejected the OLD disk once it booted, to prevent problems, I noticied that all apps were running normal (important to make sure you boot from the correct disk, since they are clones, you wouldnt notice a difference), and then reinstalled my Multibeast settings.

Removed the old disk from the usb slot before I restarted again.

Success, now, the new disk is cloned from the old disk, and has boot info re-installed onto it.

PS: if you are also planning to upgrade your OS, keep the old disk around and intact, so you have a quick and complete backup to work with just in case.

PS2: I use TimeMachine, but I unplugged it before any work just in case I needed it later, suggest you do the same.